# Subview vertical alignement with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, vertical-alignment

I try to align a container view in his parent but it doesn't respect the constraint that i try to set.

I've never user programmatic constraints before.
Subview go directly to the top when I want it to get aligned to the bottom

```
var constraintButton = NSLayoutConstraint (item: playerController.view,
                                           attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom,
                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                                           toItem: rc.view,
                                           attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0)
rc.view.addConstraint(constraintButton)
constraintButton.isActive=true
playerController.didMove(toParent: rc)
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to do `rc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: Hi! I have already tried it but it didn't change anything, playerController stay on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Parent and container view should set the property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false before you create your constraints.
Try this code:

```objectivec
playerController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Below is your constraints setting code.
var constraintButton = NSLayoutConstraint (item: playerController.view,
                                           attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom,
                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                                           toItem: rc.view,
                                           attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.bottom,
                                           multiplier: 1,
                                           constant: 0)
rc.view.addConstraint(constraintButton)
constraintButton.isActive=true
playerController.didMove(toParent: rc)
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/ I just added the storyboard, it may help, it is really simple, rootViewController (rc) with 2 Container View

Comment: Are you just setting this one constraint? Only one constraint may not be able to get your view aligned right as your thoughts. And your should fulfill all constraints to get it right. It's like you're only specifying the y axis position of the view. But the system don't know how to settle the view on x axis and how to set its width and height.